# Fortune teller lists and raw_input

Tags: python

So here is my python code I have right now, I am having a problem with looping the question if the user responds yes. And when the user responds no, it still asks them what their question. It is very  frustrating, and since i am a beginner, I cannot for the life of me figure this out. here is the code i have:

```
import random

answers = ["Of course", "No freaking way man", "I don't think so", "Maybe", "Get out of       here with that nonsense, no way!"]
question = 'What is your question? '

name=raw_input('What is your name : ')
print ("Hi %s! I am fortune teller Idris" % name)

def prompt_question(question):
    response = raw_input(question)
    print random.choice(answers)


prompt_question(question)

def ask_again():
    response2 = raw_input('Do you Have another question? ')
    if response2 == 'Yes' or 'yes' or 'Y':
         print prompt_question(question)
    elif response2 == 'No' or response2 == 'no':
        print "goodbye"
    else:
        print 'You need to say yes or no'


ask_again()
```

Any help I could get would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Non-empty strings return True.  As such `if 'yes':` will always be taken. You need to use

```
if response2 in ['Yes', 'yes', 'Y']:
```

or

```
if response2 == 'Yes' or response2 == 'yes' or response2 == 'Y':
```

**Edit**: I would write a `main()` function

```
def ask_again():
    while True:        
        response2 = raw_input('Do you Have another question? ')
        if response2 in ['Yes', 'yes', 'Y']:
            return True
        elif response2 in ['No', 'no', 'N']:
            return False
        else:
            print 'You need to say yes or no'   

def main():
    while True:
        prompt_question(question)
        if not ask_again():
            print "goodbye"
            break
```

Comment: The first option is the more pythonic, as it is easier to both write and read.

Comment: Also, your else condition in ask_again currently exits the "loop"

Comment: great, that works! but how would i make it loop to keep asking a question after i respond yes. because as soon as it asks my that other question after print prompt_question(question), the code just ends.

Comment: I added code snippet to help. You don't have `ask_again` in any sort of loop which is why it doesn't loop. @Ibrewster

Comment: the only problem with that is when i type no, it just asks me 'what is your question'. i want it to print goodbye and exit the system.

Comment: @Ibrewster, This works like that for me. I added the goodbye line

Answer (score 0):

oops:

```
    if response2 == 'Yes' or 'yes' or 'Y':
```

better:

```
    if response2 == 'Yes' or response2 == 'yes' or response2 == 'Y':
```

"anything or 'yes' " will always be true, because only empty strings ('') are false.  Or evalutes each of the things between it, not pick between a list like in english.

So in your code the machine never tries to look whether the response is "no".  It just assumes it should ask another question because 'yes' is true.